# Private folders which are not indexable

Tags: security, web-crawlers, cloud-hosting

I have a requirement where I need to distribute about 400 copies of a pdf document (about 6 MB) and .pub files, that are personalized for each user. Every user must have access to only his/her set of documents and I also need to make sure that any search engine does not index those files. I am fine with manually creating these 400x2 copies and uploading them to different folders.

I am looking for a Windows based solution which even Mac/Linux users can access.

What options do I have with me?

Comment: Do you have hosting or a web server now? If so, is it Apache, IIS, or other web server? I am assuming you are starting from scratch (nothing), but thought this question could help get you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is [possible to create a different directory for each user using FTP and IIS](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/how-to-set-up-ftp-access-for-multiple-users-with-user-isolation/). To do so you need to use the "user isolation" option when setting up FTP.

Given that you are sharing files with these users, IIS's FTP server sounds like it would be a good option for you.

Mac and Linux users can access FTP because all modern browsers support the `ftp://` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a web hosted/accessible location you are making these files available on. You could make a folder for each user and give each folder a `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file inside, thus giving each folder a unique user/password to access the content.
Going to any of the urls:

`www.example.com` `/user1` `/user2` `/user3`

Will prompt the visitor for the username and password to get content view of that folder. Here is a [htaccess password generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/) if you don't want to hand code each file.